# Ninject inject into an attributes constructor, field or method

Tags: c#, attributes, inversion-of-control, ninject, interceptor

I am wondering if the following is possible, and if so how to do it.
I'll try and explain it with code bellow.

```
public class RandomClass
{
    ...
    //class is filled with stuff of none importance for this demonstration
    ...

    [LogScope("Start", "End")] //The important LogScope attribute!
    public virtual void MyMethod()
    {
        ...
        //Doing something here but not the point now...
        ...
    }

    ...
}

public LogScopeAttribute : InterceptAttribute
{
    private readonly string _header;
    private readonly string _footer;

    public LogScopeAttribute(string header, string footer)
    {
        _header = header;
        _footer = footer;
        // This is just one of many constructors....
    }

    public override IInterceptor CreateInterceptor(IProxyRequest request)
    {
        return request.Context.Kernel.Get<LogScopeInterceptor>(
            new ConstructorArgument("header", _header),
            new ConstructorArgument("footer", _footer));
        // In the real version of this method there is more logic here for creating
        // the right version of the interceptor, in regards to what constrcutor the
        // LogScopeAttribute was called with.
    }
}

public class LogScopeInterceptor : SimpleInterceptor
{
    // No need to explain stuff here, (not of importance to the question)
    // but what the interceptor does for me is write to log
    // a header and footer and indent everything inside the logscope.
}
```

What I want is to inject a `ILogScopeInterceptorFactory` into the `LogScopeAttribute` with Ninject so I dont have to call the kernal inside the `CreateInterceptor` method, and insert `ConstructorArgument` objects
I would like to do it like this...

```
public LogScopeAttribute : InterceptAttribute
{
    private readonly string _header;
    private readonly string _footer;
    private readonly ILogScopeInterceptorFactory _logScopeInterceptorFactory;

    public LogScopeAttribute(ILogScopeInterceptorFactory logScopeInterceptorFactory ,string header, string footer)
    {
        _header = header;
        _footer = footer;
        _logScopeInterceptorFactory = logScopeInterceptorFactory;
    }

    public override IInterceptor CreateInterceptor(IProxyRequest request)
    {
        return _logScopeInterceptorFactory.Create(_header, _footer);
    }
}
```

This is the `ILogScopeInterceptorFactory` interface which I bind with the `Ninject.extensions.Factory`
like this :

`Bind<ILogScopeInterceptorFactory>().ToFactory();`

```
public interface ILogScopeInterceptorFactory
{
    LogScopeInterceptor Create(char separatorChar, string header, string footer);
    LogScopeInterceptor Create(char separatorChar, string header);
    LogScopeInterceptor Create(string header, string footer);
    LogScopeInterceptor Create(string header);
    LogScopeInterceptor Create(char separatorChar);
    LogScopeInterceptor Create();
}
```

Now what i want to do is still use the `LogScopeAttribute` like this
`[LogScope("Start", "End")]`
**Without having to manually insert the factory, just inject it, how could i do that?**

**EDIT2:**

I am using log4net to log with, I'll just write here what the `LogScopeAttribute` does,
And what the output looks like.

```
[LogScope("The Start", "The End")]
public virtual void MyMethod()
{
    logger.Info("Hello World!");
}

OUTPUT:
logger: The Start
logger:     Hello World!
logger: The End
```

In order for ninject to intercept all methods, they need to be `public` and `virtual`.
I find this pretty handy for logging, easy to indent everything logged inside a method
And if i want a header and footer, or print the execution time for the method its all there.
This can also be nested...

**@FELIX**

The problem is not that I can't get the kernel...
If I wanted to create the factory by calling the kernel I could do it like this.

```
public override IInterceptor CreateInterceptor(IProxyRequest request)
{
    var factory = request.Context.Kernel.Get<ILogScopeInterceptorFactory>();
    return factory.Create(_header, _footer);
}
```

If I manually inserted the factory I would have to do this for every attribute

```
[LogScope(_logScopeInterceptorFactory, "header", "footer")]
```

And that would just be plain uggly

Answer (score 0):

Since you cannot do anything runtime like in the attribute... you will have to cheat...

The container is global so I always create it using a singleton pattern...

```
public static class Container
{
    private static IKernel _container;

    static Container()
    {
        _container = ...; //Create the kernel and define container
    }

    public static IKernel Current { get { return _container; } }
}

public LogScopeAttribute(string header, string footer)
{
    _header = header;
    _footer = footer;
    _logScopeInterceptorFactory = Container.Current.Get<ILogScopeInterceptorFactory>();
}
```

Normally of course using the `Container.Current.Get` is an anti-pattern. However in some situations it is required (such as attributes). In an ideal world the attribute would be very slim - the `ILogScopeInterceptorFactory` would do all the work (and would be the class that is tested).

Comment: you don't have access to the kernel in the constructor, and an IResolutionRoot cant be injected just the same as I am struggling with injecting the ILogScopeInterceptorFactory. But it can be done in the CreateInterceptor method, as through the IProxyRequest object you can get to the kernel, but that would defeat the whole purpose of this question.

Comment: Sorry... looks like when i was researching this question Kernel used to be static or something... let me update my answer

Comment: I don't see how that would be any different then doing what I am already doing, the problem is not to get the kernel, i already have it... An answer would be no its no possible and explain why imo.

Comment: sure, no probs... I just saw the question as 'Without having to manually insert the factory, just inject it, how could i do that?'. It IS possible - I show an example... so you couldn't really say that it ISN'T possible. Of course there might be a better answer out there!

Comment: no problem :) I edited my question with an answer for you, to better demonstrate in code.